How can I say "it is thought" in German?
In English, one can use

It is thought that temperature will continue to rise during the next 100 years.

I don't think 'Es is gedacht, dass...' is idiomatic (by Google search).
Regarding a similar English 'people say'='it is said', I think 'Man sagt, ...' works, but not 'Es is gesagt,...'. But to me, 'Man denkt,...' looks unlikely as well.
How best is 'It is thought that...' in German? I'd appreciate any other related expressions for hearsay or general belief among people.
Disclaimer: I'm not native in English. Correct me if I'm wrong about assumptions on English.


Please check your Google search result. I highly doubt you got "is" in a German translation.

"Es ist gedacht" might be idiomatic in a completely different context and meaning "it is intended/planned for "

Nothing wrong with "Man denkt". Sure there's alternatives, but so there are for the original English phrase, and it is the literal translation.


It is thought that temperature will continue to rise during the next 100 years.
Es wird angenommen, dass die Temperatur in den nächsten 100 Jahren weiter ansteigt.
Man nimmt an, dass die Temperatur in den nächsten 100 Jahren weiter ansteigt.

The relevant verb phrase is

etwas annehmen — to expect, to assume


Note that there is a difference between saying "Es wird angenommen, ..." and "Angenommen, ...". The latter is more commonly used as "If ..."

The OP mentions "Es ist gesagt, dass ...", which is close to correct, because "Es wird gesagt, dass ..." is indeed idiomatic.

What about "es wird geglaubt"?

That's uncommon in this context because glauben is about trust.

It is not entirely clear, for which context you intend the translation. What you would hear in the news would probably sound like:

Man geht davon aus, dass die Temperaturen...

or even more succinct:

Man erwartet für die nächsten 100 Jahre...

Note the following to combat desinformation
Assuming, that this is not stated earlier: To indicate the person, group or consortium  voicing this expectation, I would recommend neither the passive voice from your example nor the man given here but something like:

Die Klimaforscher des xxx Instituts erwarten für die nächsten 100 Jahre....


I agree. Passive voice often indicates (in many contexts) that someone is trying to evade responsibility.
